# Javascript navigation menu is blinking

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a navigation menu with sublinks. When I put my mouse on a link who have sublinks, it is blinking when moving my mouse over the links.

Illustration of my problem :

https://i.ibb.co/g684pXt/illustr.gif

```js
function myFunction(i) {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown" + i).classList.toggle("show");
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function yourFunction(i) {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown" + i).classList.toggle("show");

  document.getElementById("myDropdown" + i).children.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```html
<li class="active"><a href="{{ route('comparateur') }}">{{__('header.Comparer')}}</a></li>
<div class="d_1">
  <button href="{{ route('vpn.index') }}" onmouseover="myFunction(1)" class="d_btn">{{__('header.Meilleurs-VPN')}} <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" onmouseout="yourFunction(1)" class="d_content d_mobile_1">

    <a href="{{ route('vpn.index') }}">Tous les VPN</a>

    <a href="{{ route('vpn.windows') }}">Windows</a>
    <a href="{{ route('vpn.ios') }}">{{__('header.Mac')}}</a>

    <a href="{{ route('vpn.linux') }}">{{__('header.Linux')}}</a>
    <a href="{{ route('vpn.android') }}">{{__('header.Android')}}</a>
    <a href="{{ route('vpn.netflix') }}">{{__('header.Netflix')}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works but the navigation is not fluid, not good because of when I move the mouse in the submenu, the submenu is blinking between each link.

Any help, please! Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you could create a example that is interactive, and include your css.

Comment: I added a gif file that describe the issue

Comment: 1. You need to add the relevant CSS code. 2. You need to check your code. `children.classList` doesn't make any sense, because children returns several elements. You can write `children[0].classList` but you need to loop if you're going to use `children`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch javascript and go with pure CSS. `:focus` selects the element when you clicking on it, and `x + y` means "select `y` if it's directly following `x`".

```css
button:focus + div {
  display: flex;
}

button + div {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* ALL DECORATION BELOW AND NOT RELEVANT TO THE ISSUE */
button + div {
  padding: 0.5rem 0px;
  background: pink;
}

button + div > a {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

button + div > a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
```

```html
<div class="d_1">
  <button href="{{ route('vpn.index') }}" class="d_btn">{{__('header.Meilleurs-VPN')}} <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="d_content d_mobile_1">

    <a href="{{ route('vpn.index') }}">Tous les VPN</a>

    <a href="{{ route('vpn.windows') }}">Windows</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, I learned https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp here  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/position and I did what I wanted easily !